# QUERY Select cells equals to an array from another tab

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, join, select

I want to import in a google sheet , the data of URLTab, only where Col 1 is equal to the column A of Tab2.

When I use the following formula, refering to only the first row of Tab2, it works fine.

```
=QUERY(Importrange("URL";"URLTab!A3:P");"select * where Col1 =  '"&Tab2!A2& "'")
```

When I try to refer to the whole column A, it gives an error :

```
=QUERY(Importrange(""URL";"URLTab!A3:P");"select * where Col1 is not null and Col1 matches'"&JOIN("|",  '"&Tab2!A2:A6& "'")"))
```

Could you please help me on the 2d formula ?

Thank you

Comment: It would be great if sample data is available.

Comment: Use a [sample Spreadsheet Maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some extraneous single and double quotes within the JOIN. At a guess, try this:

```
=QUERY(Importrange("URL";"URLTab!A3:P");"select * where Col1 is not null and Col1 matches '"&JOIN("|";Tab2!A2:A6)&"'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an alternative, I'd use filter combined with Let after you have the URL data, instead of using Query.

```
=let(allData,QUERY(A1:F10,"select *"),zMatchcol,Tab2!A:A, 
filter(allData,ISNUMBER(match(CHOOSECOLS(allData,1),zMatchCol,false))))
```